# How to handle firmware if schematic changes in StmCubeIDE

Tags: version-control, firmware

I am working with STMCubeIDE on an embedded project.
I have 2 different versions of our PCB. The difference between the 2 versions is that, there are 3 MCU pins which are routed differently.
A1, A2, A3 pins are for Buzzer, LCD_Data and LCD_Clk in Schematic 1 and
A6, A7, A8 pins are for Buzzer, LCD_Data and LCD_Clk in Schematic 2.

What is the best way to handle this in firmware? The constraint is that, both schematics will be in use together..
A) Making 2 repositories in git is not an option.

B) Should I use Guard macros? But in this solution, if I add another MCU pin via the IOC file, STMCubeIDE will regenerate the files and my Guard Macros would get deleted. So every time, I would have to be extremely careful.

Requesting some ideas and/or suggestions